# Как перехватить исключение VkAPIError на Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь перехватить исключение, порождаемое слишком большим числом запросов (№6):

```
for user in users:
    try:
        d=api.users.get(user_ids=user)[0]
    except VkAPIError:
        time.sleep(0.333)
        d=api.users.get(user_ids=user)[0]
    if d.get('deactivated')!=None:
        dogs.append(d.get('uid'))
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Python выдаёт:

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is
>   not allowed

Comment: кст, `if d.get('deactivated')!=None:` можно было заменить на `if 'deactivated' in d`. зы, тоже недавно писал скрипт для поиска "собачек" в группах вк.

Answer (score 4):

Данное исключение является пользовательским, поэтому его нужно импортировать из модуля vk

> from vk.exceptions import VkAPIError

Comment: `TypeError` намекает, что имя `VkAPIError` у вас определено, но ссылается не на исключение, в противном случае вы бы NameError получили бы. Убедитесь, что ваш код нигде  не переопределяет `VkAPIError`